# Customize Search Window Odoo 10

Tags: odoo-10, odoo-view

I'm busy creating a custom module for Odoo 10.
Part of it is to make sure Products are displayed with a default Group By in the Search Window.
I can't seem to find the view/template where that could be organised.
Has anybody an idea?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you want to group by `categ_id`.  Then all you need to do is add a new filter like this:

```
<filter name="groupby_categ_id"
string="Internal Category"
context="{'group_by': 'categ_id'}"/>
```

And you will have to add this filter by default with the action context:

```
<field name="context">
{'search_default_groupby_categ_id': 1}
</field>
```

#### edit:

You can also pass this as a context of a field as follows:

```
<field name="product_tmpl_id" 
context={'search_default_groupby_categ_id': 1}
/>
```

And then when clicking on `Search more` the filter will be on by default.

Comment: Thanks Milán!
I understand what you write.
But the question is: Where is the action for the "Search more" link triggered?
For example when you create a new Sale Quotation and want to add an item, you want to choose a product from the list and click on Search more. Where is that action triggered?

Comment: Thanks a lot Milán.